# Cannot open pixbuf loader module file in Windows

Tags: coq, installation

I installed Coq from the 8.15 64-bit installation file in Windows. I ran coqide and got the error message:

`GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Cannot open pixbuf loader module file`

It says to run gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders for a temporary fix but there is no such program on my system. Do I have to download and install another program?

If this is just a temporary fix, is there is permanent one?

Added: I am new to Coq so I can't really tell what is working and what is not. CoqIDE did appear and I managed to run a program with `Check 0.` and `Check nat.`, but then it crashed. For now I'll work through the tutorials from the command line and hope that eventually someone can help us unfortunately people who use Windows....

Comment: Does coqide still run? If that's the case it's safe to ignore the warning

Comment: I can reproduce and the IDE runs. It's just the terminal window is very annoying

Comment: @ice1000 I don't get the warnings, do you need to do anything particular? Do the icons display properly?

Comment: @Couchy everything is fine except that CoqIDE always comes with a terminal window with warnings